# How do multiple Mobile Processing Labs work?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

> Related: [How does the Laboratory work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221842/how-does-the-laboratory-work)

I had a orbital station with 1x Mobile Processing Lab (MPL-LG-2)  in LKO. With another small vessel I did a tour of Mun and Minmus, collecting science as I went and finally docking with the station. Now I've got way too much data being processed way too slow.

[image: MPL]

If I dock another MPL (or 2), will they work my existing station? Will I be able to process data faster? Do they interact? Or should I just launch another MPL to rendezvous (but not dock) and manually transfer the science?

Comment: I am not sure, but one thing I know is that processing speed of a lab depends on the experience level of the scientists in the module.

Comment: I have 2 MPLs currently processing data on my station, and they seem to be producing more science than an individual MPL could, but perhaps not as much as 2 could if orbiting different bodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store additional data (analysed science) in additional labs but if they are connected to the same structure, the science must be different to what you've already analysed to be allowed to analyse it though (as opposed to having several labs disconnected from each other allowing the exact same science experiment to be used in each lab).

Data will not be processed faster per lab, but having two labs will allow twice the processing.

The rate is determined by how much data is in the lab, and the level and number of *all* scientists in the complex, not just in the labs.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a multiple MPL setup, but KSP currently does not support using more than one MPL in one craft. When storing data it will only fill *one* of the labs, once that lab is full you will be unable to store data in other labs. This makes any other lab you have attached completely useless.

One trick to get around this would be to simply undock labs as they fill up with data. Once you're done transferring data you could redock the MPLs.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Joe's comment:
You don't have to undock/redock the mlp module.
If you have space left, put the kerbals from the full mlp into another module.
Then the data will be added into the other mlp (if there is at least one kerbal inside).
Afterwards, put the kerbals back.

Comment: Hi Eldorim! Welcome to Arqade, the Gaming Stack Exchange community. Unlike most forums, where a thread consists of a bunch of responses to an original post, this community distinguishes between comments and answers. Your post is an excellent comment, but it doesn't answer the Question, and therefore shouldn't be an Answer.